# Using two detail bands with pagebreak in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Well, i have the following situation:

I should create a report (using iReport) that prints a "PRICE TAG" for each product in database, but this "PRICE TAG" have 2 sides (FRONT SIDE and BACK SIDE), and this 2 sides must be in different pages, but same REPORT.

1 - If i put the FRONT and BACK side into same DETAIL BAND, both sides will be in same page (and as i said, i don't wanna this).

2 - If i put the FRONT side in DETAIL 1 and BACK Side in DETAIL 2 and insert a "page break component" into DETAIL 2, the images will be in different pages as i hope BUT i need configure Report Height equal to = (Detail band Height 1) + (Detail Band height 2), and this makes apper a big white space in each detail band.

How can i fix this problem ?

**SOLUTION**

In fact, this is a "iReport Bug" and i will explain why. The iReport don't let you set a page size less than total of detail height, the page size must be equal or bigger. But when i add a "page break component", the detail band in each page will fill all page size, giving a big white space. So, the solution is configure page size before everything.

Comment: why don't you put both in the same band detail 1 and add between them a page break it will put the BACK into another page you just have to adjust height in detail 1

Comment: The page height must have the sum of FRONT and BACK side (Ex: 300+300 = 600 height of page) And when i use page break in this way i big white space apper in each page, i wanna fit the detail to IMAGE height

Comment: i don't think its possible to do what you want maybe they is somewhere a solution but i don't see how since each page height is base from select template so any time i print a report is fit correctly to a standard paper size 8 1/2 by 11 inches. You better switch to landscape template for your need.

Comment: This is a problem for me, i just need that page size don't have any white space. I tried use "ignore pagination" but this ignores the page break component.